# Read one more item in IEnumerable<> reading loop?

Tags: c#, linq

The following simplified code iterates an `IEnumerable<int>`. I want it print

```
1
2
==> 3
4
```

Any way to do it without using IEnumerator?

```
IEnumerable<int> r = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};
foreach (var line in r)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    if (line == 2) 
    {
        var n = r.GetOneMore????();
        Console.WriteLine("==> ", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help clarify the question: do you want the third item in the sequence or the second to last (penultimate) item? In your sample code, these two are the same, but the approaches are going to be a bit different in the more general case.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the condition last in the loop and keep the state to the next iteration:

```
IEnumerable<int> r = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};
bool marked = false;
foreach (var line in r) {
  if (marked) {
    Console.Write("==> ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine(line);
  marked = line == 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot modify a foreach loop like that. if your IEnumerable allows it, use a for loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is no way to "read one more item" in a foreach. By using this structure you are committing to looping once for each item, unless you choose to terminate early.

I would go further and say that attempting to produce two lines of output for one iteration of a loop of this kind would leave a casual reader to expect a total of N+1 lines of output, not N. This would be misleading. I would not do it.

There are multiple strategies for arranging that an item inspected in one iteration can influence the behaviour of another. What it looks (to me) like you want to do is introduce a lag. I would do it this way.

```
IEnumerable<int> r = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};
int prevline = -1;
foreach (var line in r) {
    if (prevline == 2)
        Console.WriteLine("==> ", n);
    else Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```